# Converting data type Number to varchar2

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

I'm currently working on creating a stored procedure in PL SQL that will turn a data type number 4 to the varchar2 to A.

```
  SELECT s.sname, g.sid, s.sid, c.cid, g.cid,
  CAST(CASE g.grade
      WHEN 4 THEN 'A'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'B'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'C'
      WHEN 1 THEN 'D'
      WHEN 0 THEN 'F'
      ELSE 'No Value'
      END AS varchar2(55)) AS Grades
      FROM student s, grades g, class c
      WHERE c.cid = g.cid
  AND g.sid = s.sid
  AND g.sid = s.sid;
```

This is works as is but once I add in this in a create procedure it errors out as Unexpected error 
          Error code -6502: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error:character to number conversion error.

Also, I have tried adding the below within the procedure and return the same error.

```
EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND; -- exit check
    dbms_output.put_line('Student Name: '|| s_sname); 
    dbms_output.put_line('Class Name: ' || c_cname);
    dbms_output.put_line('Grade: ' || to_char(g_grade, 'ABCDF');
    dbms_output.put_line('-----------------');
```

In the above I'm trying to print the letter grade and not the numerical grade.

Comment: Can you post the procedure code. Since your select statement is working, no point of looking at it out of the procedure context

Comment: "*character to number*" means that `g.grade` is a character value (e.g. `VARCHAR2`), but since your `WHEN` clauses are numeric, it implicitly converts the text to number, *except* that there exists a record where the value of `grade` cannot be converted to number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste the entire code. It works for me.

```
create table testing(i int);
insert into testing values (0);
insert into testing values (1);
insert into testing values (2);
insert into testing values (3);

create or replace procedure p
is
begin
  for i in (select CAST(CASE g.grade
   WHEN 4 THEN 'A'
   WHEN 3 THEN 'B'
   WHEN 2 THEN 'C'
   WHEN 1 THEN 'D'
   WHEN 0 THEN 'F'
   ELSE 'No Value'
   END AS varchar2(55)) AS Grades
 from testing
 )
 loop
   dbms_output.put_line(i.Grades);
 end loop;
end;
/

set serveroutput on;

begin
  p;
end;
/

D
C
F
B

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```